# VHDL Loops - Only last increment is done

Tags: vhdl

I have a problem with for loops in below code - in the simulation it shows like the only last increment of the loop is done, for example:

On the inputs I give (obviously in 8-bit SIGNED for the w0, w1, w2):

```
x1 = 1; x2 = 1; w0 = -32; w1 = 63; w2 = 63
```

and on the output I recieve `u = 31` instead of `u = 94.`
So it seems the equation is:

```
u = (x2 * w2) - w0
```

Instead of:

```
u = (x1 * w1) + (x2 * w2) - w0
```

I know that the loops in VHDL works differently than in C, but the usage of variables should do the trick. Unfortunately, I'm missing something. What it might be?

```
  LIBRARY IEEE;
    USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

    ENTITY NeuronBehavioral IS
         GENERIC ( n: INTEGER := 1;
                      m: INTEGER := 2;
                      b: INTEGER := 8);
        PORT ( x1  : in   STD_LOGIC;
               x2  : in   STD_LOGIC;
               w0  : in   SIGNED (b-1 downto 0); --11100000 (-32)
               w1  : in   SIGNED (b-1 downto 0); --00111111  (63)
               w2  : in   SIGNED (b-1 downto 0); --00111111  (63)
               u   : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (b-1 downto 0));
    END NeuronBehavioral;

    ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF NeuronBehavioral IS
        TYPE weights IS ARRAY (1 TO n*m) OF SIGNED(b-1 DOWNTO 0);
        TYPE inputs IS ARRAY (1 TO m) OF SIGNED(b-1 DOWNTO 0);
        TYPE outputs IS ARRAY (1 TO n) OF SIGNED(b-1 DOWNTO 0);
    BEGIN
        PROCESS (w0, w1, w2, x1, x2)
            VARIABLE weight: weights;
            VARIABLE input: inputs;
            VARIABLE output: outputs;
            VARIABLE prod, acc: SIGNED(b-1 DOWNTO 0);
        BEGIN
            input(1)  := "0000000" & x1;
            input(2)  := "0000000" & x2;
            weight(1) := w1;
            weight(2) := w2;
            L1: FOR i IN 1 TO n LOOP
                acc := (OTHERS => '0');
                L2: FOR j IN 1 TO m LOOP
                    prod := input(j)*weight(m*(i-1)+j);
                    acc := acc + prod;
                END LOOP L2;
                output(i) := acc + w0;
            END LOOP L1;
            u <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(output(1));
        END PROCESS;
    END Behavioral;
```

Testbench:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY NeuronTB IS
END NeuronTB;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF NeuronTB IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT NeuronBehavioral
    PORT(
         x1 : IN  std_logic;
         x2 : IN  std_logic;
         w0 : IN  SIGNED(7 downto 0);
         w1 : IN  SIGNED(7 downto 0);
         w2 : IN  SIGNED(7 downto 0);
         u : OUT  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal x1 : std_logic := '0';
   signal x2 : std_logic := '0';
   signal w0 : SIGNED(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal w1 : SIGNED(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal w2 : SIGNED(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    --Outputs
   signal u : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: NeuronBehavioral PORT MAP (
          x1 => x1,
          x2 => x2,
          w0 => w0,
          w1 => w1,
          w2 => w2,
          u => u
        );

   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      wait for 100 ns;

            x1 <= '1';
            x2 <= '1';
            w0 <= "11100000";
            w1 <= "00111111";
            w2 <= "00111111";

        wait for 100 ns;

            x1 <= '1';
            x2 <= '0';
            w0 <= "11100000";
            w1 <= "00111111";
            w2 <= "00111111";

        wait for 100 ns;

            x1 <= '0';
            x2 <= '1';
            w0 <= "11100000";
            w1 <= "00111111";
            w2 <= "00111111";


        wait for 100 ns;

            x1 <= '0';
            x2 <= '0';
            w0 <= "11100000";
            w1 <= "00111111";
            w2 <= "00111111";

      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

Comment: Can you provide testbench?

Comment: Is this code meant for synthesis? This will be very resource hungry this way. What are your requirements?

Comment: That's right. The end goal is to use it on ML506 board (Virtex-5). This code is a part of neural network that I'm trying to programme. Do you have any ideas what's might be the problem of current malfunction and what can I do later to improve it?

Comment: There's an out of bounds error for `prod := input(j) * weight( m * (i - 1) + j);`. The right hand expression of type signed will have a length of the sum of the lengths of multiplicand (`input(j)`) and multiplier (`weight( m * (i - 1) + j)`). What tool are you using that didn't provide a run time error? (Re: a [mcve], you can test this code directly by providing default values for all inputs. Depending on VHDL revision a report statement with to_string(output(1) can show the answer.)

Comment: `variable prod: signed(b * 2 - 1 downto 0);` and `acc := acc + prod (b - 1 downto 0);` produce `neuronbehavioral.vhdl:58:9:@0ms:(report note): u = 01011110` with `report "u = " & to_string (output(1));` added before the end of the process. It looks like you should examine the lengths of prod, acc and u.

Comment: I'm curious if you will manage to get this to work. It will probably be a very enlightening journey for you. Keep us informed ;)

Comment: Actually yes. It works perfectly now thanks to the answer by user1155120. It's just one piece of the whole NN I'm trying to implement so probably I will come back because I'm sure there will be problems with other pieces :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question did not originally provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), lacking the means to replicate the error much less the expected result. That's not the total barrier to the actual problems.

There's an out of bounds error for

```
prod := input(j) * weight( m * (i - 1) + j);
```

The right hand expression of type signed will have a length of the sum of the lengths of multiplicand (`input(j)`) and multiplier (`weight( m * (i - 1) + j)`).

Detecting the eventual  effective value produced by evaluating the projected output waveform from the right hand expression in an assignment statement has a matching element for each element of the target is required by the standard (see IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3.4 Signal update, -1993 thru -2002 12.6.2 Propagation of signal values).

(When tools allow suspension of performing this check by command line flag or configuration it's with the expectation that it would have been done at some point and that there's a performance increase in eliminating it.)

With regards to no needing an MCVe some simulators allow running a model with top level ports. This problem can identified by providing default values for all inputs. Depending on VHDL revision a report statement with to_string(output(1) can show the original cited answer.

```
port ( 
    x1:   in   std_logic := '1'; -- default added
    x2:   in   std_logic := '1'; -- default added
    w0:   in   signed (b-1 downto 0) := to_signed(-32,b); --11100000 (-32) -- default added
    w1:   in   signed (b-1 downto 0) := to_signed(63, b); --00111111  (63)
    w2:   in   signed (b-1 downto 0) := to_signed(63, b); --00111111  (63)
    u:    out  std_logic_vector (b-1 downto 0)
);
```

When run with ghdl the design specification produced a bounds failure in loop L2.

In the unlabeled process changing the declaration of prod:

```
    variable prod: signed(b * 2 - 1 downto 0);
```

And the assignment to acc:

```
                acc := acc + prod (b - 1 downto 0);
```

Allowed the calculation to complete, producing

> `neuronbehavioral.vhdl:58:9:@0ms:(report note): u = 01011110`

With an added last statement to the process:

```
        report "u = " & to_string (output(1));
```

For non VHDL-2008 compliant simulators a to_string function can be added to the declarative region of the process statement:

```
        function to_string (inp: signed) return string is
            variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
            alias input_str:  signed (1 to inp'length) is inp;
        begin
            for i in input_str'range loop
                image_str(i) := character'value(std_ulogic'image(input_str(i)));
            end loop;
            return image_str;
        end function;
```

Note the report value is the 8 bit signed value for 94.

Also the declarations for prod, acc and u should be examined to insure the design is capable of producing a result within the bounds of input values for w0, w1 and w2.

Not only is VHDL strongly typed, it's particular about mathematical meaning. It's an error if a result is incorrect, hence the product of the "*" operator has a length sufficient to produce a valid mathematical result. This can be seen in the numeric_std package body.

With the above patches to the design specification the testbench produces:

> ```
> ghdl -r neurontb
> neuronbehavioral.vhdl:58:9:@0ms:(report note): u = 00000000
> neuronbehavioral.vhdl:58:9:@100ns:(report note): u = 01011110
> neuronbehavioral.vhdl:58:9:@200ns:(report note): u = 00011111
> neuronbehavioral.vhdl:58:9:@300ns:(report note): u = 00011111
> neuronbehavioral.vhdl:58:9:@400ns:(report note): u = 11100000
> ```

Because `input(j)` can only be "00000000" or "000000001" based on the inputs `x1` and `x2`) there's an alternative to the above changes:

```
    prod :=  resize(input(j) * weight( m * (i - 1) + j), b);
```

The multiplier result can be resized (taking the least significant b length bits). the left most multiply is either by 0 or by 1.

Because the value of `input(j)` is either zero or one (as an 8 bit signed value) the first multiply can eliminated:

```
architecture foo of neuronbehavioral is
    type weights is array (1 to n*m) of signed(b-1 downto 0);
    -- type inputs is array (1 to m) of signed(b-1 downto 0); -- CHANGED
    type inputs is array (1 to m) of std_logic;
    type outputs is array (1 to n) of signed(b-1 downto 0);
begin
    process (w0, w1, w2, x1, x2)
        variable weight: weights;
        variable input: inputs;
        variable output: outputs;
        -- variable prod: signed(b * 2 - 1 downto 0);  -- RESTORED:
        variable prod: signed(b - 1 downto 0);
        variable acc: signed(b - 1 downto 0);

        function to_string (inp: signed) return string is
            variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
            alias input_str:  signed (1 to inp'length) is inp;
        begin
            for i in input_str'range loop
                image_str(i) := character'value(std_ulogic'image(input_str(i)));
            end loop;
            return image_str;
        end function;

    begin
        -- input(1)  := "0000000" & x1;  -- CHANGED
        -- input(2)  := "0000000" & x2;  -- CHANGED
        input := x1 & x2;    -- ADDED
        weight(1) := w1;
        weight(2) := w2;
l1: 
        for i in 1 to n loop
            acc := (others => '0');
l2: 
            for j in 1 to m loop
                if input(j) = '1' then   -- ADDED
                -- prod := input(j) * weight( m * (i - 1) + j); -- CHANGED
                    prod :=  weight(m * (i - 1) + j);  -- ADDED
                else                                   -- ADDED
                    prod := (others => '0');           -- ADDED
                end if;                                -- ADDED
                -- acc := acc + prod (b - 1 downto 0); -- RESTORED:
                acc := acc + prod;
            end loop l2;
            output(i) := acc + w0;
        end loop l1;
        u <= std_logic_vector(output(1));
        report "u = " & to_string (output(1));
    end process;

end architecture foo;
```

For the second multiplier calculating the index for `weight` observe that all the variables are either generic constants or declared implicitly in loop statements. While the latter are dynamically elaborated at execution time in VHDL their value is considered static during traversal of the sequential statements in the each loop statement.

The sequence of statements in a loop statement are unrolled in synthesis. The equivalent in concurrent statements would be through the use of for generate statement replicating the various statements as concurrent statements. Note this would require signals (shared variables are not portable nor guaranteed to be supported for disparate vendor tool chains).

A concurrent statement version would look something like:

```
architecture foo of neuronbehavioral is
    type weights is array (1 to n*m) of signed(b - 1 downto 0);
    type inputs is array (1 to m) of std_logic;
    type outputs is array (1 to n) of signed(b - 1 downto 0);
    signal weight: weights;
    signal input: inputs;
    signal output: outputs;

    function to_string (inp: signed) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  signed (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'value(std_ulogic'image(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end function;
begin
    weight <= w1 & w2;
    input  <= x1 & x2;

l1: 
    for i in 1 to n generate
        type accums is array (1 to m) of signed (b - 1 downto 0);
        signal accum: accums;

        function acc (inp: accums) return signed is
            variable retval: signed (b - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        begin
            for i in accums'range loop
                retval := retval + inp(i);
            end loop;
            return retval;
        end function;
    begin
l2: 
        for j in 1 to m generate
            accum(j) <= weight(m * (i - 1) + j) when input(j) = '1' else
                        (others => '0');
        end generate;
        output(i) <= acc(accum) + w0;
    end generate;

    u <= std_logic_vector(output(1));

MONITOR:
    process
    begin
        wait on x1, x2, w0, w1, w2;
        wait for 0 ns;
        wait for 0 ns;
        wait for 0 ns;
        wait for 0 ns;
        report "u = " & to_string (output(1));
    end process;

end architecture foo;
```

Where no multiply is used and all the statically indexed elements are accumulated in two places. The `wait for 0 ns;` statements in the MONITOR process are to overcome delta delays in 0 delay assignment through successive signals. (Somewhere there's something doing discrete events, for `x1` and `x2` if for no other purpose.)

This gives the same answer as above:

> ```
> ghdl -r neurontb
> neuronbehavioral.vhdl:169:9:@100ns:(report note): u = 01011110
> neuronbehavioral.vhdl:169:9:@200ns:(report note): u = 00011111
> neuronbehavioral.vhdl:169:9:@300ns:(report note): u = 00011111
> neuronbehavioral.vhdl:169:9:@400ns:(report note): u = 11100000
> ```

and represents the same hardware.

Comment: Thank you for that. The code meets it's purpose now thanks to your perfect answer. I've learnt a lot.